# In socket, what happen if we take SOCK_STREAM as second and UDP as third argument in socket()?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

normally we take `0` as third argument of `socket()` so by default here it will take TCP as transmission protocol. but what if we take UDP in place of `0` ?

Comment: why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: @SouravGhosh because he can't reliably test what happens. It might simply be UB.

Comment: @usr checking the success [failure] of a system call and the `errno` are the basics.

Comment: @usr Either it succeeds or it  fails. If it fails the function returns -1 and there is an `errno` value to interrogate. The concept of undefined behaviour comes from language specifications, not system libraries.

Comment: @EJP not all library calls fully validate their parameters. If a lib author does not specify what happens when invalid parameters are passed it is possible to have UB. That said I don't think this is the case here. Also, the call might succeed only under certain situations. This is not testable. I think the question is valid.

Comment: The question is testable and it is also answerable from the *man* page. `socket()` is not a 'library call', it is a system call, and system calls *must* validate their parameters. Otherwise crashes would occur, if. For example an invalid pointer parameter was provided.

Answer (score 1):

The call would likely fail(socket() returns -1), and you can inspect `errno` to see why.
On linux, this happens:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc,char argv[])
{
  int rc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  printf("rc = %d errno = %d : %s\n", rc, errno, strerror(errno));
  return 0;
}
$ gcc t.c
$ ./a.out
rc = -1 errno = 93 : Protocol not supported
```